# how to display both x,y coordinate values using react recharts library?

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I want to display both the x and y coordinates values, when i hover over the point on my chart. I am using react recharts library. Right now it is only displaying Y coordinate value, and not x. How can I achieve this?
here is my code -

```
import { LineChart, XAxis, YAxis, CartesianGrid, Line, Tooltip, ReferenceLine } from 'recharts';

const Chart = ({ chartData }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <LineChart
        width={1000}
        height={500}
        data={chartData}
        margin={{
          top: 10,
          right: 30,
          left: 30, // Adjusted left margin to make room for y-axis labels
          bottom: 10, // Adjusted bottom margin to make room for x-axis labels
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray='3 3' />

        {/* Set domain for XAxis and include a reference line at y=0 */}
        <XAxis dataKey='x' domain={['auto', 'auto']} />
        <ReferenceLine x={0} stroke='black' />

        {/* Set domain for YAxis and include a reference line at x=0 */}
        <YAxis dataKey='y' domain={['auto', 'auto']} />
        <ReferenceLine y={0} stroke='black' />

        <Line type='monotone' dataKey='y' stroke='#ccc' />
        <Tooltip />
      </LineChart>
    </>
  );
};

export default Chart;
```

Comment: I run your code, showing the x value and 'y: value'. can you provide an image of your problem?

Comment: here on my output, only the y-value is visible, and not the x-coordinate value.
I am afraid I can't share an image..